# How do i make my discord bot wait till the current song has ended rather than skipping the current song in the queue when a new one is added

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im trying to make a discord music bot feature for my bot. whenever i use the play command the bot stops the current song playing and immediately starts playing the new song i queued, how do i make it wait for the current song to end and then move to the next one in the queue.

```
var servers = {};

function play(connection, message) {
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];
    const dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], { filter: 
        "audioonly" }));

    server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], { filter: 
    "audioonly" }));

    dispatcher.on('error', console.error);

    server.dispatcher.setVolume(0.2);

    server.dispatcher.on("end", function () {

        server.queue.shift();

    if (server.queue[0]) play(connection, message);
    else connection.disconnect();

});

}

Crashbot.on('message', async message =>{

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

switch (args[0]) {
 case "play":
        if (!args[1]) {
            message.reply(`You need to put a link after ${PREFIX}play to add a song to the queue`)
            return;
        }
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
            message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel to use this command")
            return;
        }
        if (!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
            queue: []
        }
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        server.queue.push(args[1]);

        if (!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function (connection) {
                play(connection, message);
        });
        break;
 case "skip":
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        if (server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
        break;

 case "stop":
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        if (message.guild.voiceConnection) message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect();
        break;
}

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either keep state of the current song playing through a variable or look at the lib you’re using to play the songs to see if there’s a status check.

**Option 1**

global status or create a class that holds your play instance with status. Then when the play on hits end or you disconnect due to someone hitting stop, then you change status.

The idea is that when a user hits play to add the new song to the queue, and status is `paused/stopped` then play the song. If status is `playing` then you just add song to queue and don’t call the play function

**Option 2**

Depends on your library, so look at the docs to better understand what’s available When it comes to current play status. Once you have that then follow same status checks as provided in option 1